# ActionSupport and EventHandler Error

Tags: visualforce, error, actionsupport

I am completely new to coding and I need help with below:
[image: I am getting this error after selecting save]

Error   Error: page1 line 10, column 24: The element type "apex:column" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "" 
Error   Error: The element type "apex:column" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.contacts}" var="ac">
             <apex:column > 
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseover" reRender="ren"/>
                     {!ac.name}
                     <apex:param value="{!ac.id}" name="cid"/>
                 </apex:actionsupport>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!ac.phone}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>

 <apex:outputPanel id="ren">

 <apex:detail />


 </apex:outputPanel>

 <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false"/>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a silly syntax issue with closing the action:function tag

Try below code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.contacts}" var="ac">
         <apex:column > 
         {!ac.name}
             <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseover" reRender="ren">

                 <apex:param value="{!ac.id}" name="cid"/>
             </apex:actionsupport>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!ac.phone}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>

 <apex:outputPanel id="ren">
   <apex:detail />
</apex:outputPanel>

 <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

> Carefully note that i am not closing the actionSupport tag in line 10